# Xcode 15 command line simulator build ignores simulator destination

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

This command to build for simulator works just fine with Xcode 14:

```bash
xcodebuild \
    -project MyProject.xcodeproj \
    -scheme App \
    -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14" \
    -derivedDataPath ../../derivedData \
    clean build
```

But on Xcode 15 it gives this error:

> MyProject.xcodeproj: error: "App" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'App' from project 'MyProject')

This error is not true. Although I do not have provisioning profiles set up, I do not need them for simulator builds. In fact the Xcode 15 GUI can build this project for simulator just fine without them.

I'm pretty confident that Xcode 15's version of `xcodebuild` is completely ignoring the `-destination` argument because I see this warning right before it fails:

```
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00006000-0008316802D8801E }
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
...
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:5575F133-1565-4864-882C-78E3EA80F618, OS:17.0, name:iPhone 14 }
```

Clearly the one I want is in that list. Why does it think it didn't match?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Xcode 15. Once I deleted the simulator and recreated it with the exact same name, the same build command worked fine.

I've submitted this bug to Apple as FB13665510.